# How do you redirect standard input to a file in the Windows command line?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, stdin, cat

On Unix I would do something like:

```
cat > file.txt
```

How can I do this on the Windows command prompt or batch file?

**EDIT:** Basically, I am looking for the functionality of `cat` with no arguments (it reads from stdin and spits it back out to stdout).

Comment: `type thisfile > output.txt` pushes all output same as unix cat `type thisfile >> output.txt` appends all output to file without overwriting

Comment: +1 for using `type` such a cool and simple solution.

Comment: @DominicP except that it does not work for my purposes (read after the "EDIT:")

Comment: @Matt, yeah it's not quite the same. I'm not sure how much you've worked with the Windows shell, but finding such a close approximation to *nix functionality is pretty rare/nice in my experience. :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`TYPE CON`

CON is the MS-DOS device for console input.  You can redirect to a file as follows:

`TYPE CON>output.txt`

To terminate, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> = EOF).

Comment: Ah lol!  It might be useful for others though I guess...  I'm probably the only person my age who knows of the elegant `TYPE CON>LPT1` shortcut to turn MS-DOS into a typewriter!

Comment: Windows alternatives to many *nix commands do exist - but they "evolved" rather than being intelligently designed as bash was, so they're a bit harder to find and often far more complex to use than they should be...  A great example of this difference is the bash backtick vs. the equivalent `FOR` construct in DOS.  Thank heavens for Powershell and C#script!

Comment: Ah how could I ever have forgotten to mention Cygwin on this dual-boot machine? :D

Comment: Also, `COPY CON output.txt`

Comment: -1 because it doesn't work: it does not read from stdin but from the console. The OP asked for the stdin. I tested it on win10.

Comment: On win10 you need a little C program looping fgetc/fputc

Comment: @robert4: What's the difference between stdin & console?

Comment: @Zimba: [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6447947/1348138), or the difference between `echo hello | find "hello" >first.txt` and `echo hello | type con >second.txt`. first.txt will contain `hello` without asking for typing, but for second.txt you have to type in something

Answer (score 13):

If all you want is to read stdin and write what you read to stdout, then FINDSTR may work, depending on how you use it.

FINDSTR will output an exact binary image of the input as long as the input is specified as a single file name at the end of the argument list.

```
findstr "^" file.txt
```

Pipes or redirection may also work, depending on the content of the input:

```
findstr "^" < file.txt
or
type file.txt | findstr "^"
```

The output will be corrupted if any of the following occur while using redirected or piped input with FINDSTR:

- Any input line > 8191 bytes
- Last line of input is not terminated by \n. (command may hang if redirected input)

FINDSTR will not work if multiple input files are specified because in that case the name of the file will be used as a prefix to each line of output.

FINDSTR also differs from cat in that it cannot read from both stdin and a named file.

See [What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844868/what-are-the-undocumented-features-and-limitations-of-the-windows-findstr-comman) for more info.

Comment: EDIT - Corrected info about piped input having CR/LF appended. Added info about XP and Windows 7 potentially hanging with redirected input

Comment: Thank you for this answer! For anyone else out there, a batch file that writes (appends) stdin to file "foo.txt" is:

findstr "^" >>foo.txt

Comment: @dbenham - `findstr "^" < %windir%\system32\calc.exe > c.exe` gives `Line is too long` error on Win7.  Not suitable for binary copying?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff - Pipes and redirection limit FINDSTR input line length. Specify the input file as an argument (simply remove the `<`) rather than use redirection, and it should work. See **Line Length limits** section at https://stackoverflow.com/a/8844873/1012053 for more info.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff - I've updated the answer to include the line length limitation.

Comment: @dbenham - Thanks.  Actually, I'm trying to find how could I copy binary data from ADS to separate file, I was hoping the following would work: `findstr "^" < file.txt:hidden.exe > hidden.exe`.  Unfortunately, `findstr` doesn't consider ADS as a valid file name: `findstr "^" file.txt:hidden.exe > hidden.exe` (error: `Can't open file "file.txt:hidden.exe"`).  `type` doesn't work either. So I have to use redirection `<` to access ADS. I'm searching for a Win7 utility that reads binary stdin and writes it to stdout (or to an output file). Didn't find it yet.  Could you give a hint?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff - Your issue deserves its own question - you should post one. I'm not aware of any native batch utilities that will work. I suspect something could be written with another scripting language, especially powershell. But I haven't much experience with ADS, so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 10):

I think `more.exe` might be what you are looking for assuming you are working with text data (this will break binary data).

It can take input both from the console:

```
more > file1.txt
```

Or piped in from another file, which `TYPE CON` **doesn't** handle:

```
type file1.txt | more > file2.txt
```

(`more` seems to append a newline to your file and expands tabs, so don't use it on binary data!)

Comment: Actually this one helped when i had mutiple lines.Thank you

Comment: Nice. This is the only one that worked with stdin. The other solutions only piped con or from another file.

Answer (score 0):

Standard input:

Batch file:

```
:: set /p MyVar=   Prompts user for stdin information

set /p MyVar=

echo %MyVar% > filename
```

Comment: This would have to read the entirety of stdin first though, wouldn't it? It seems like it would be impractical if stdin is very large.