# Why do I get 'Bad file descriptor' when trying sys.stdin.read() in subversion pre-revprop-change py script?

Tags: python, svn, svn-hooks

I'm trying pre-revprop-change hook script on a Windows machine, but find a tough problem.

I distill my problem to the following scenario:

I have *C:\csvn\data\repositories\tr1\hooks\pre-revprop-change.bat* with content:

```
D:\svntest\testhook.py %*
exit %ERRORLEVEL%
```

*testhook.py* is:

```
import os, sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # sys.stderr.write(sys.version+'\n') # this is OK, tried.
    newtext = sys.stdin.read() # try to read new log message

    sys.stderr.write('newtext is: %s\n'%newtext)

    exit(2)
```

However, when doing a client-side `svn propset svn:log --revprop -r 2 "newtext"` , I got python error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\svntest\testhook.py", line 5, in <module>
    newtext = sys.stdin.read() # try to read new log message
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

**What's the cause of this error?**

It seems that *pre-revprop-change.bat* does not pass STDIN handle to the py script. Yes, I verified that *pre-revprop-change.bat*  can fetch text from STDIN(according to instructions in [Read stdin stream in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6979747)).

I also tried to run *pre-revprop-change.bat* directly from command line, `sys.stdin.read()` is OK.

Please kindly help me out.

Screen shot below:

[image]

Env:

- Windows Server 2003
- Collabnet Subversion Edge 2.3(svn 1.7.3 and Apache 2.2.22)
- Install Python 2.7.1 msi from python.org

＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝[LATEST UPDATE]＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝

**I'm sorry to say: I should have written in the .bat**

```
exit %ERRORLEVEL%
```

instead of

```
exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
```

For someone who have tried it with me, please fix it and try again. The `/b` seems to have pre-revprop-change.bat always exit with 0. TIP: Without `/b`, running the .bat directly from a cmd window will cause the cmd window to close, so we'd better try it with `cmd /c "pre-revprop-change.bat some param"`.

**Quick way to reproduce this problem below**

What's more, for those who is still interested, please

- download this file package http://down.nlscan.com/misc/chjsvnpyhook.zip ,
- extract them to D:\ ,
- cd into D:\svntest\tr1_local ,
- run elog.bat (`svn propset svn:log --revprop -r 2 "newtext"`)

then my problem will be reproduced. (Requirement: svn.exe 1.7 command line(whether collabnet or TortoiseSVN), and Python 2.7 installed)

If you still cannot reproduce the error. I've prepared a VMware virtual machine that exhibits the problem exactly. Download the VM at http://down.nlscan.com/misc/chj/winxp-svnhook-py-stdin-error.7z (link expected to be valid until Sep 2013). VMware Player 3.0(free) is sufficient to run that VM.

＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝[WORKAROUND FOUND]＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝

Very nice workaround provided by @nmenezes, with `c:\Python27\python.exe D:\svntest\testhook.py %*` in bat .

Comment: Why don't you use the .py file directly?

Comment: I believe I can do this on Linux. But on Windows, svn refuse to call pre-revprop-change.py directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVN is executing the script without an associated console. 
So you won't see anything displayed on STDOUT.
Everything sent to STDERR is displayed as a message on SVN, if the script returns an error code different of 0.

This kind of script should run unattended, it is independent of input or output from the user.

You can try to pass the property value as an extra command line parameter. 
To do so, change your .bat to:

```
@echo off
set /p NEWTEXT=
test.py %* %NEWTEXT%
exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
```

And the .py to:

```
import os, sys

if __name__ == '__main__':   
    newtext = sys.argv[6]
    sys.stderr.write('newtext is: %s\n'% newtext)
    exit(2)
```

I read the batch STDIN to NEWTEXT variable and I pass it to your script as an extra command line parameter.

This solution does not work for multiple lines values. So, I tried again your original solutions and it worked fine.

```
svn propset svn:log --revprop -r 3 -F svn.txt
```

In this case, the property value is read from the svn.txt file, a text file with multiple lines. In this case, the option with set /p does not work, as we discussed in the comments. But the original script works.

For information, 5 properties are passed on the command line:

1 - repository

2 - revision number

3 - user

4 - property name

5 - operation (M in this case)

The property value is passed on the stdin of the batch script.

@Chen, I finally downloaded the image. The problem is solved when you change the hook batch to:

```
c:\python27\python.exe d:\svntest\testhook.py %*
exit %ERRORLEVEL%
```

It looks that the way your XP machine executes python directly is misconfigured.

Comment: Yes. TESTVAR will contain something from STDIN. But the problem is: once the pre-revprop-change.bat launch some process, that process lose STDIN.

Comment: Did you run these lines inside pre-revprop-change.bat ?

Comment: Yes, exactly in pre-revprop-change.bat .

Comment: Unfortunately, the ``set /p`` skill does not work well. As stated in this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/6980605/151453 , and confirmed myself, ``set /p`` only reads one line(and probably cannot be called multiple times in order to read all lines). But you know, svn log message may contain may lines. Anyway, thank you for getting involved.

Comment: Hi Chen, I tested on my Windows machine... and I got no problems reading stdin with the Python script, as you did on the first post. I'm start to think we are missing something here. I will do another test tomorrow.

Comment: I have an important fix on .bat. Please remove ``/b`` from .bat and try again.

Comment: Hi Chen, which version of SVN are you using? I tested your script, that reads from stdin without problems. I also passed a file with multiple lines as the property value and it worked ok. In another test, I tried to read a second time stdin, no problems at all. Are you sure we are testing the same scripts? Do you call any other programs before the python script?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16876/discussion-between-jimm-chen-and-nmenezes)

Comment: I've tried quite many versions, on many virtual machines(VM), e.g Collabnet official subversion client 1.7.6, and TortoiseSVN 1.7.7 . I will prepare a WinXP VM(VMware format) that exactly shows the problem on the spot. The VM will be available for download tomorrow.

Comment: Chen, the image download broke at 650 MB. I'm downloading it again. I download the quickway you posted, but it works for me. Tested with multiline and it is also works ok. I'm using SVN: svn, version 1.7.6-SlikSvn-1.7.6-X64 (SlikSvn/1.7.6) X64

Comment: Very nice workaround with ``c:\Python27\python.exe D:\svntest\testhook.py %*``, confirmed. Thank you! But I'm fairly sure I did not do any special config to my Windows and honestly use the python.org Win32 Python 2.7 package. I'll save it for later investigation.

Comment: It behaves like pythonw.exe was used for .py files, instead of python.exe. This is the only possible cause I found for the lack of stdin. I checked the registry of the virtual machine and everything looks fine. Good to know it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it up to your batch file to direct the stdin it received into the script that it calls?

For reference:  http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true

Maybe you can just prefix the call to your script with the > symbol to have this happen?

```
> D:\svntest\testhook.py %*
exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
```

It seems like if the batch file can read from stdin, then SVN is doing what it is supposed to and it is up to your batch file to make that available to the additional script that you call.

Comment: I think I got your idea. For workaround, I can tell the .bat to write STDIN content to a tmpfile then later read that tmpfile in my py script.  But, the baffle is: Why the py script can inherit STDIN if .bat is run directly from CMD line, but it can't if invoked from svn hook procedure.

Comment: Excuse me, I don't know what do you mean by "prefix the call to your script with the > symbol" ...

Comment: I fixed the formatting, sorry did not notice it before.  Does that answer question about what I meant?

Comment: No, writting ``> D:\svntest\testhook.py %*`` in pre-revprop-change.bat wipes out my testhook.py (i.e. testhook.py becomes 0 byte).

Comment: Sorry about that, and doh! of course that is what that will do.  I wonder if pipe ( | ) would work?  You might be able to use the findstr command to read the stdin and then pipe the output into your script.

Comment: I have tried the findstr skill in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10824973/151453 in order to have findstr dump STDIN to a file, but in vain; I see findstr falls in dead loop eating 100% CPU. I think findstr also encounters the broken STDIN and goes nuts.