# How to dump STDIN to a file, using C++ STL?

Tags: c++, stl

I'm writing this program so to make a workaround in this issue: [Why do I get 'Bad file descriptor' when trying sys.stdin.read() in subversion pre-revprop-change py script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12453354)

Note:

- Content from STDIN may be arbitrary binary data.
- Please use C++ STL functions, iostream, ifstream etc .
- If the file creation/writing failed, I'd like to catch the exception to know the case.

Comment: Would like some coffee and a cookie while folks work that out for you?

Comment: Heaven forbid you dig into those scary big books and might have a learning experience for yourself...

Answer (score 3):

The shortest version and probably the fastest one on most systems is this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::ofstream("cin.txt", std::ios_base::binary) << std::cin.rdbuf();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, very concise. I added ios_base::binary to your code, otherwise, a single \n will be converted to \r\n on Windows.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed this issue. I'm a UNIX guy - it doesn't matter on UNIXes.

Comment: But... I tried, if cin.txt is read only, that ofstream code does not throw an exception. Could you do further improvement?

Comment: You can check the status of the expression in an `if` statement. To cause the stream to potentially throw (and potentially get some description of what went wrong) you'd need to set an exception mask (I never found a good use of stream exceptions, though).

Comment: Could you update the code? I just want to know whether cin.txt is written successfully, --which I think is a decent request.

Answer (score 1):

I think  copy method is what you want:

```
template<class InputIterator, class OutputIterator>
OutputIterator copy ( InputIterator first, InputIterator last, OutputIterator result )
{
  while (first!=last) *result++ = *first++;
  return result;
}
```

for example:

```
copy(istream_iterator<string>(cin)
       , istream_iterator<string>()
       , ostream_iterator<string>(fout, "\n"));
```

here the fout is a file stream iterator.

Comment: I assume you meant to point out this is [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy), and this is just an example implementation.