# Windows equivalent for "cat -"

Tags: windows, cat

Can someone please shed some light on an equivalent method of executing something like "cat file1 -" in Linux ?
What I want to do is to give control to the keyboard stream (which is "-" in linux) once the content of file1 is displayed.

Comment: Perhaps you might find your solution here?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60244/is-there-replacement-for-cat-on-windows   I'm not entirely sure if the "-" suffix is also part of the "type" or "echo" behaviour, though

Answer (score 2):

You can't achieve that in Windows using a single command, however you can use 2 commands on a single line:

```
type file.txt && type CON
```

This will print the contents of "file.txt" and if that command was successful it will give control to the keyboard stream (using a special keyword called CON).

**Tip**: To stop, hit Ctrl + C or Ctrl + Z and Enter.

Remember to replace "file.txt" with your file!

Sources:

- https://superuser.com/questions/434870/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-the-unix-command-cat
- [How do you redirect standard input to a file in the Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824178/how-do-you-redirect-standard-input-to-a-file-in-the-windows-command-line/16566534)

Answer (score 0):

type command

```
c:\type myfile.txt
```

reference
https://superuser.com/questions/434870/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-the-unix-command-cat